# how can I read real-time updated data from postgresql(or mysql) through spark streaming(or kafka)?

Tags: java, python, database, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I get a real-time updated data from postgresql,and want to pipeline the real-time data to a fixed model to get a customer predicted through spark streaming or kafka.

please recommend any blog and exact code that working well,or any information /suggestions you know.postgresql/mysql real time updated data to python/java environment is also fine!thanks!

Or maybe it's just no way to fulfill this?

Answer (score 0):

This is my anwser，hope can help you.

My spark version is 2.2.0. The programming language is Python.

The data flow come from kafka to mysql and the kafka version is 0.9.

note:
you must be found correct jars with mysql and kafka, you can go to the official website to find this.

code like this :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# note: the mysql's driver is must be correct

def getSparkSessionInstance(sparkConf):
    if ('sparkSessionSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sparkSessionSingletonInstance'] = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .config(conf=sparkConf)\
            .getOrCreate()
    return globals()['sparkSessionSingletonInstance']

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # mysql config
    url = "jdbc:mysql://your_server:3306/spark_test"
    table_name = "word_info"
    username = "root"
    pasword = "root"

    # spark context init
    para_seconds = 10
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, para_seconds)

    # receiver in kafka
    brokers = 'kafka1:9092'
    topic = 'two-two-para'

    # get streaming datas from kafka
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})

    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])

    # Convert RDDs of the words DStream to DataFrame and run SQL query
    def process(time, rdd):
        print("========= %s =========" % str(time))

        if (rdd.isEmpty()):
            return

        try:
            # Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
            spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())

            # Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to DataFrame
            rowRdd = rdd.map(lambda w: Row(word=w))
            wordsDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRdd)

            # Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame.
            wordsDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("words")

            # Do word count on table using SQL and print it
            wordCountsDataFrame = \
                spark.sql("select word, count(*) as word_count from words group by word")
            wordCountsDataFrame.show()

            wordCountsDataFrame.write \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", url) \
            .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver") \
            .option("dbtable", table_name) \
            .option("user", username) \
            .option("password", pasword) \
            .save(mode="append")

        except Exception as e:
            print("Some error happen!")
            print(e)

    lines.foreachRDD(process)


    # start job
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```